# How to segue modal without losing tab bar controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Okay, so I want to be able to have a TabBar Controller with two Tabs (like the template in Xcode), but inside the Second tab, I want to have a button that takes the view to a Third View Controller. I want the Third View Controller to have a back button to the Second Tab, I don't want the Third View to retain the TabBar, but when I go back to the Second Tab I want the TabBar to return.

So this is what I actually did, and it doesn't work. I put a button in 2nd view and 3rd view, and I control clicked and dragged to the respective views, and clicked modal. Everything works, except when I go back to the 2nd view I lose the tab bar.

Pictures of what I am talking about:

Screen Shot of Xcode:

Screen  Shot of iOS on 2nd view:

Screen Shot of after I click button to go to third view:

Screen Shot of after I Click button to go back to second view. ( lose tab bar !)

http://s13.postimage.org/78gqghflj/Screen_Shot_2012_07_09_at_2_03_41_PM.png
http://s16.postimage.org/gdwus4w6t/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_shot_Jul_9_2012_2_02_50_PM.png
http://s10.postimage.org/5uq3ste7d/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_shot_Jul_9_2012_2_02_57_PM.png
http://s8.postimage.org/gpmsx959x/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_shot_Jul_9_2012_2_03_54_PM.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a separate modal Segue back to the Second View Controller, you can just dismiss the modal view controller when "Back to Second View" is clicked

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks! As of 6.0 dismissModalViewControllerAnimated is deprecated, but using dismissViewControllerAnimated still works.